# Get the parent controler in a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ListView with a list of name and I want to be able to rename each value by double click or with a button.

I already did this for the doubleclick and it's working using this :

WPF

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ListProfileView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ProfilesCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.RenameCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiConverter}">
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}"/>
                                    <Binding Source="{x:Static classes:BooleanHelper.False}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.RenameCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiConverter}">
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}"/>
                                    <Binding Source="{x:Static classes:BooleanHelper.True}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

c# (MVVM model with ICommand):

```
private ICommand _renameCommand;
/// <summary>
/// Command used to change the name of the selected profile.
/// </summary>
public ICommand RenameCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _renameCommand ?? (_renameCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(obj =>
        {
            if(!(obj is object[] values)) return;
            if(!(values[0] is TextBox txtBox) || !(values[1] is bool value)) return;

            txtBox.IsReadOnly = value;
            if (!value)
            {
                txtBox.Focus();
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

But for the button, I don't know how to get the path to the textbox to use the same command.
I tried things like that :

```
<Button Grid.Column="3" Content="{x:Static dictionnaries:ColorConfigurationDictionnary.rename}"
        FontWeight="SemiBold"
        Command="{Binding RenameCommand}">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="ListProfileView" Path="ItemContainerGenerator"/>
            <Binding Source="{x:Static classes:BooleanHelper.False}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

But I'm out of idea... Is that possible ?

Comment: If your `ViewModel` knows about a `TextBox` then this is **NOT** MVVM. ViewModel should NEVER know about UI components. Use the underlying objects in your `ProfilesCollection`, which I hope is not a collection of `Controls`. When you change these bits then you can manipulate the collection and all changes will be reflected in UI.

Comment: @XAMlMAX To use mvvm, I should put this king of methode (renaming item with the UI) inside the UI code ?

Comment: yes, in your view handle double clicking, editing and everything and then just change the property in ViewModel, still form view

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek thank you ! Just to be sure, in my VM, i should never have any ref to a controler ?

Comment: If you want to rename the content of the TextBoxes which are representation of the objects inside of your collection in your ViewModel then use a Command like you are now but instead of using TextBoxes use the contents of your collection so: `foreach(var item in ProfilesCollection) {item.Name = "<yourTextHere>";}`

Comment: yes, or as XAMIMAX said, pass down text instead of textbox.

Comment: Ok thank you both ! I'll try that and mark as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did:
that let me change the name of one value only by disabling the readonly of the textboxes in the list view.
I wrote that in the GUI code behind.

```
private ICommand _renameCommand;
/// <summary>
/// Command used to change the name of the selected profile.
/// </summary>
public ICommand RenameCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _renameCommand ?? (_renameCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(obj =>
        {

            if(!(obj is object[] values)) return;


            if(!(values[0] is TextBox || values[0] is SetConfiguration) || !(values[1] is bool value)) return;

            if (values[0] is TextBox txtBox)
            {
                txtBox.IsReadOnly = value;
                if (!value)
                {
                    txtBox.Focus();
                    txtBox.SelectAll();
                }
            }

            if (values[0] is SetConfiguration config)
            {
                var listView = ListProfileView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(config) as ListViewItem;
                var presenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(listView);
                if(!(presenter.ContentTemplate.FindName("ProfileName", presenter) is TextBox txtBoxItem)) return;
                if (!value)
                {
                    txtBoxItem.Focus();
                    txtBoxItem.SelectAll();
                }
                txtBoxItem.IsReadOnly = value;
            }

        }));
    }
}

private static TChildItem FindVisualChild<TChildItem>(DependencyObject obj)
    where TChildItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child is TChildItem item)
            return item;

        var childOfChild = FindVisualChild<TChildItem>(child);
        if (childOfChild != null)
            return childOfChild;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is some sort of misinformation going about so let me describe how MvvM works in the best way I can think of.
Model is where you store your data so let's call that a profile:

```
namespace Model
{
    public class Profile
    {
         public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now what you need is a ViewModel which will provide Information which is manipulated data:

```
using VM.Commands;

namespace VM
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ProfilesCollection = new List<Profile>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                ProfilesCollection.Add(new Profile() {Name = $"Name {i}"});
            }
            RenameCommand = new TestCommand(renameCommandMethod, (o) => true);
        }

    void renameCommandMethod(object parameter)// to manipulate the colleciton you use the Commands which you already do but without the need for converters or any UI elements. Makes it much easier to handle.
    {
        string renameTo = parameter.ToString();
        foreach (var profile in ProfilesCollection)
        {
            profile.Name = renameTo;
        }
    }

    private List<Profile> profilesCollection;   

    public List<Profile> ProfilesCollection
    {
        get { return profilesCollection; }
        set { profilesCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private ICommand renameCommand;

    public ICommand RenameCommand
    {
        get { return renameCommand; }
        set { renameCommand = value; }
    }
```

And the implementation of the `RelayCommand`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace VM.Commands
{
public class TestCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _execute;
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    public TestCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #region Implementation of ICommand

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute?.Invoke(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    #endregion
}
}
```

Then UI looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="SO_app.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VM;assembly=VM"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:SO_app.Converters"
    xmlns:validation="clr-namespace:SO_app.Validation"
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO_app"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Model;assembly=Model"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="452.762" Width="525" Closing="Window_Closing">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding ProfilesCollection}" x:Key="profiles"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Background>
    <VisualBrush>
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="ForestGreen"></Rectangle>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Window.Background>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource profiles}}" 
              VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <ToolTip x:Key="Tip">
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run>Some text here</Run>
                            <LineBreak/>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='Actual Text: {0}'}"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </ToolTip>
                </DataTemplate.Resources>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{StaticResource Tip}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <Button Content="Rename" Command="{Binding RenameCommand}" CommandParameter="NewName"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

---

What this gives you is:
* Clean UI without any converters
* Every operation is done in the ViewModel without passing any UI elements.
* In UI you would do stuff like Styles with animation or setting font for text elements. But avoid handling clicks there. It is possible and sometimes it can't be avoided but try to utilise your ViewModel to manipulate the data.
BTW there are no controllers in here.
If you have any questions just ask.

Comment: Thank for this ! I was not that far but had some misunderstanding. I think I didn't explain correctly what I wanted to do. I already do almost all code change in my VM. Here it's a UI interraction I wan't to do. I have the list like you describe, and when I click on that button, it set thet selecteditem editable. In my case I use isReadOnly (true by default to avoid editing and when I click that button it should pass to False).

Comment: Is it one button for a `SelectedItem` or is it a button per item? If it's a button for a `SelectedItem` then use another command then use a different command to alter the `SelectedItem.Name` property and it will work fine.

Comment: it is one button for all of them. I succed something. I finished to code it and I'll post it.